# Java decryption from CryptoJS

Tags: java, angularjs, encryption, aes

I'm trying yo decrypt Java-size some informations previously crypted in CryptoJS (angualrjs).
Here are some code snippet:

**Encryption in Angularjs**

```
CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, "my secret key").toString();
```

**Decryptionin Java**

```
package com.mypackage;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;
 
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AES {
private static SecretKeySpec secretKey;
private static byte[] key;

public static void setKey(String myKey) {
    MessageDigest sha = null;
    try {
        key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
        sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        key = sha.digest(key);
        key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); 
        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    } 
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secret) {
    try{
        setKey(secret);
        
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, AES.secretKey);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

**Calling java decrypt method**

```
@PostMapping("/decryption")
public ResponseEntity<DecryptResponseBean> decryption(@RequestBody DecryptRequestBean data){
    String dataToDecrypt = data.getData();
    String decrypted = AES.decrypt(dataToDecrypt, "my secret key");
    
    DecryptResponseBean responseBean = new DecryptResponseBean(decrypted);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(responseBean);
}
```

I'm obtaining the following exception:

**java.security.InvalidKeyException: Parameters missing**

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT1 full stacktrace of Exception**

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Parameters missing
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:469)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineInit(AESCipher.java:313)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:805)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:867)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1252)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1189)
    at com.ses.aes.AES.decrypt(AES.java:53)
    at com.ses.services.Encryption.decryption(Encryption.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Error while decrypting: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Parameters missing
```

**EDIT2: set of sample data**

```
Key: 1234567890123456 (Both Angular and Java side)

Clear data: this is my text

Chipered data in CryptoJS: U2FsdGVkX18C7J5wy5R5FRjfP5Xghpry3FtuTj5xq+o=

What Java backend receives: U2FsdGVkX18C7J5wy5R5FRjfP5Xghpry3FtuTj5xq+o=
```

Comment: Can you include the actual stack trace so users can see _where_ and when the Exception occurs in the provided code!

Comment: ... and it could be helpful to provide a full set of sample data (plaintext, key and ciphertext = encrypted text). Please edit your post and append the data, thanks.

Comment: Added requested details, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little search here on Stackoverflow you could have found the same solution as this here. The important code is not from myself but taken from the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41434590/8166854 by author @Codo, so all credit go to him.

Crypto.JS is deriving the key and initialization vector (iv) from a passphrase ("key") so the method `GenerateKeyAndIV` is responsible to get key and IV.

**The following code has no proper exception handling and is for educational purposes only.**

result:

```
Java decryption from CryptoJS
decrypted text: this is my text
expected data:  this is my text
```

code:

```
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        System.out.println("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63484091/java-decryption-from-cryptojs");
        System.out.println("Java decryption from CryptoJS");
        String secret = "1234567890123456";
        String cipherText = "U2FsdGVkX18C7J5wy5R5FRjfP5Xghpry3FtuTj5xq+o=";
        String expectedData = "this is my text";
        // decode base64 encoding
        byte[] ciphertextData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText);
        byte[] saltData = Arrays.copyOfRange(ciphertextData, 8, 16);
        // generate key & iv
        MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        final byte[][] keyAndIV = GenerateKeyAndIV(32, 16, 1, saltData, secret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), md5);
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyAndIV[0], "AES");
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(keyAndIV[1]);
        // get encrypted data without iv
        byte[] encrypted = Arrays.copyOfRange(ciphertextData, 16, ciphertextData.length);
        Cipher aesCBC = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        aesCBC.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
        // decryption
        byte[] decryptedData = aesCBC.doFinal(encrypted);
        String decryptedText = new String(decryptedData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        System.out.println("decrypted text: " + decryptedText);
        System.out.println("expected data:  " + expectedData);
    }

    /**
     * Generates a key and an initialization vector (IV) with the given salt and password.
     * <p>
     * This method is equivalent to OpenSSL's EVP_BytesToKey function
     * (see https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/evp/evp_key.c).
     * By default, OpenSSL uses a single iteration, MD5 as the algorithm and UTF-8 encoded password data.
     * </p>
     * @param keyLength the length of the generated key (in bytes)
     * @param ivLength the length of the generated IV (in bytes)
     * @param iterations the number of digestion rounds
     * @param salt the salt data (8 bytes of data or <code>null</code>)
     * @param password the password data (optional)
     * @param md the message digest algorithm to use
     * @return an two-element array with the generated key and IV
     * answered Jan 2 '17 at 23:38 author Codo
     * https://stackoverflow.com/a/41434590/8166854
     */
    public static byte[][] GenerateKeyAndIV(int keyLength, int ivLength, int iterations, byte[] salt, byte[] password, MessageDigest md) {
        int digestLength = md.getDigestLength();
        int requiredLength = (keyLength + ivLength + digestLength - 1) / digestLength * digestLength;
        byte[] generatedData = new byte[requiredLength];
        int generatedLength = 0;
        try {
            md.reset();
            // Repeat process until sufficient data has been generated
            while (generatedLength < keyLength + ivLength) {
                // Digest data (last digest if available, password data, salt if available)
                if (generatedLength > 0)
                    md.update(generatedData, generatedLength - digestLength, digestLength);
                md.update(password);
                if (salt != null)
                    md.update(salt, 0, 8);
                md.digest(generatedData, generatedLength, digestLength);
                // additional rounds
                for (int i = 1; i < iterations; i++) {
                    md.update(generatedData, generatedLength, digestLength);
                    md.digest(generatedData, generatedLength, digestLength);
                }
                generatedLength += digestLength;
            }
            // Copy key and IV into separate byte arrays
            byte[][] result = new byte[2][];
            result[0] = Arrays.copyOfRange(generatedData, 0, keyLength);
            if (ivLength > 0)
                result[1] = Arrays.copyOfRange(generatedData, keyLength, keyLength + ivLength);
            return result;
        } catch (DigestException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            // Clean out temporary data
            Arrays.fill(generatedData, (byte)0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solved the problem, it seems I can correctly crypt/decrypt data from Frontend to Backend. Thanks a lot!