# ionic v3 AES 256 algorithm to using encrypted not able to decrypt in java AES/GCM/noPadding algorithm

Tags: java, ionic-framework, ionic3

We are developing the ionc v3 based mobile app and we have to encrypt the password at front side and needs to decrypt the password at java middleware level. now ionic v3 we did sample encryption but the encrypted data not able to decrypt in our java. please advise as below ionic and java code, where we have to change it exactly.

ionic v3 AES 256 sample code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AES256 } from '@ionic-native/aes-256';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular/index';
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  text: string;
 private secureKey:string ;// Any string, the length should be 32
 private secureIV:string ;
 private password = "test@123"
 
  EncryptedData :string;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private aes256: AES256, private platform: Platform) {
 
   this.generateSecureKey(this.password);
  this.generateSecureIV(this.password);
  }
  

  generateSecureKey(password) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.aes256.generateSecureKey(password).then((secureKey)  => {
          this.secureKey = secureKey;
          console.log('Secure Key----', secureKey);          
        }, (error) => {
          console.log('Error----', error);
        });
    });
  }
  generateSecureIV(password) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.aes256.generateSecureIV(password).then((secureIV)  => {
        this.secureIV = secureIV;
          console.log('Secure Key----', secureIV);          
        }, (error) => {
          console.log('Error----', error);
        });
    });
  }
  encrypt() {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
   
  this.aes256.encrypt(this.secureKey, this.secureIV, this.text)
  
  .then(res =>  {alert('Encrypted Data: '+res)
  console.log("Secure Key" +this.secureKey);
  console.log("Secure Key" +this.secureIV);
  this.EncryptedData = res;
  console.log(EncryptedData);
  })
  .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
   });
 }
 decrypt() {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.aes256.decrypt(this.secureKey, this.secureIV, this.EncryptedData)
  .then(res => { alert('Decrypted Data : '+res)
  console.log("Secure Key" +this.secureKey);
  console.log("Secure Key" +this.secureIV);
  
})
  .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));

});
 }
}
```

Java Code sample:

```
package com.test.reactapi;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;


public class TestEncry {
    
    private static final String ENCRYPT_ALGO = "AES/GCM/NoPadding";

    private static final int TAG_LENGTH_BIT = 128;

    private static final Charset UTF_8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    
    
    public static String encrypt(byte[] pText) throws Exception {
        String password = "test@123";
        byte[] salt = getRandomNonce(32);
        byte[] iv = getRandomNonce(12);
        SecretKey aesKeyFromPassword = getAESKeyFromPassword(password.toCharArray(), salt);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPT_ALGO);
        cipher.init(1, aesKeyFromPassword, new GCMParameterSpec(TAG_LENGTH_BIT, iv));
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(pText);
        byte[] cipherTextWithIvSalt = ByteBuffer.allocate(iv.length + salt.length + cipherText.length).put(iv).put(salt)
                .put(cipherText).array();
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherTextWithIvSalt);
    }

    public static SecretKey getAESKeyFromPassword(char[] password, byte[] salt)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("SHA256");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 65536, 256);
        return new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(), "AES");

    }

    public static String decrypt(String cText) throws Exception {
        
        byte[] plainText = null;
        
        try {
        String password = "test@123";
        byte[] decode = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cText.getBytes(UTF_8));
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(decode);
        byte[] iv = new byte[12];
        bb.get(iv);
        byte[] salt = new byte[32];
        bb.get(salt);
        byte[] cipherText = new byte[bb.remaining()];
        bb.get(cipherText);
        SecretKey aesKeyFromPassword = getAESKeyFromPassword(password.toCharArray(), salt);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPT_ALGO);
        cipher.init(2, aesKeyFromPassword, new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv));
        plainText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new String(plainText, UTF_8);
    
    }
    
    public static byte[] getRandomNonce(int numBytes) {
        byte[] nonce = new byte[numBytes];
        new SecureRandom().nextBytes(nonce);
        return nonce;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
            System.out.println("Decrypted pwd:" + decrypt("kkkkkk/kllmnn=="));
}
    
    

}
```

please advise and help us

error :

```
java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.get(HeapByteBuffer.java:151)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.get(ByteBuffer.java:715)
    at com.test.reactapi.TestEncry.decrypt(TestEncry.java:62)
    at com.test.reactapi.TestEncry.main(TestEncry.java:90)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:515)
    at com.test.reactapi.TestEncry.decrypt(TestEncry.java:73)
    at com.test.reactapi.TestEncry.main(TestEncry.java:90)
```

Comment: Kindly share some sample data that is used on ionic side (plaintext ciphertext and full key & iv).

Comment: Plain Text : Test1234,Cipher Text : 77be64b6202dbbf43bfdce7669722b9c , Secure KeyIV : 4e744cdb33c7b1fc , Secure Key :  83ad865d4b1a319ff3a283faa9675aac , pass Key:        test@123

Comment: According to https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-aes256-encryption you should use AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding on Java side but not AES/GCM/NoPadding. When sharing sample data please use the full length of key & iv (32 and 16 byte but not 8 bytes as in your code. And what is 'pass Key: test@123' good for, I didn't see any variable that should hold it.

Comment: Hi I have edited my code and you will easily understand now. the problem is if encrypted any password, i can't decrypt at java code level. can you please help us.

Comment: In your comment you say that the 'Cipher Text' is '77be64b6202dbbf43bfdce7669722b9c' but I believe this value is wrong. According to the cordova-docs the output of the encrypt-function is a Base64-string and your ciphertext will be converted in a 24 byte long byte array - this can't be the output of an AES encryption (has to be multiple of 16). Kindly recheck your sample data.

Comment: i test ionic side and able to decrypt this chiperText. as per ionic docs we implemented. however, let me check again.   ionic docs :  https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/aes256/

Comment: in front end AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding using and back end using AES/GCM/NoPadding using. how to do we handle this. can you please suggest. the back end team escalating need more strength of security so that we looking for solution common

Comment: I'm sorry but you need to use the same AES mode on decryption side as it was used on encryption side. As per ionics-cordova-repro the only available mode is CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING".