# Ionic 3 Native AES256 encrypted data is not 24 byte format

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

We are developing and using the Ionic 3 Native AES 256 algorithm to encrypt the data, the out put of encrypted data is not valid format of ciphertext format(24 byte). so that we can't able to decrypt in java programme side. also our middleware team using `AES/GCM/NoPadding` but ionic native plugin using `AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING` so that we could not able to decrypt the data in java based middleware side. please advise, how do we handle this.

ionic docs : https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/aes256/

Answer (score 0):

As commented in your first question regarding this topic
([ionic v3 AES 256 algorithm to using encrypted not able to decrypt in java AES/GCM/noPadding algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63811173/ionic-v3-aes-256-algorithm-to-using-encrypted-not-able-to-decrypt-in-java-aes-gc)) I run the ionic encryption with these data:

```
password = "test@123"
plaintext = "Test1234" 
and received a Base64-encoded ciphertext string like "izMYpAIMvsCKIVjiNztsrA=="
```

(as the encryptionKey & iv is generated with random elements your results will differ).

Decoding this ciphertext string back to a byte array I get a (byte array) length of 16 and NOT 24 (it has to be always a multiple of 16) so your encryption isn't running well when getting a length of 24!

Second: there is no way to work with different AES modes - ionic does only support CBC mode that has to be used on your middleware decryption as well. If you need to use an authenticated encryption like "GCM" mode you have to use an additional library.

Comment: what is additional lib we have to use?, is it required ionic side or middleware side. please help me

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not have any idea about AES-libraries for ionic (you don't need an additional for Java because Java is supporting AES GCM mode).

Comment: yes, java we can do but ionic not possible as of now. this is what i told my teams, we have to use CBC to CBC . however, thanks for your support and given valuable input.